# Is there a way to sync google contacts to your iPhone?

Tags: iphone, sync, google-sync, google-contacts, mobileme

Is this possible? and can it be as seamless and transparent as using MobileMe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Google actually uses the Microsoft Active Sync Protocol that essentially turns your GMail account into a Microsoft Exchange type of account.

Check out:
http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.html#p=apple

Comment: Well, it uses the ActiveSync **protocol**. I wouldn't say it uses ActiveSync **technology**.

Comment: @Jon: I've made the change...

Comment: Thanks. I wouldn't want anyone to think we were just running a bunch of Exchange servers ;)

Comment: As soon as I saw your response I started laughing because I knew that would be the case :)

Comment: You'd be amazed at what some people think we do :)

Answer (score 10):

You can do this easily with no additional software.  Just follow the steps [outlined here on Google's site](http://www.google.com/support/mobile/bin/answer.py?answer=138740&topic=14252). I use this to sync my Google Contacts and Calendar.  It works very well!

**Edit:**
Please note that this currently only works for Contacts and Calendar and does not sync your email.  You will have to set up your email separately.

Comment: NuevaSync will do Push Email on top of contacts and calendaring, but its a paid for feature

Comment: I've been doing this for months and its just fantastic.  Now if only they'd add Gmail sync support, the circle would be complete.

Comment: I agree, Gmail sync support would be nice.  I hope Google is working on that!

Comment: Link seems to be broken.

Answer (score 4):

Check out either [Google Sync](http://www.google.com/mobile/products/sync.html#p=default) or [NuevaSync](http://www.nuevasync.com), both work in a similar way to MobileMe, but using the Exchange ActiveSync protocol

Answer (score 3):

There's an option in iTunes to do this. It's where you set contacts, you can select Google contacts, and provide your login/password. This works fine on a PC, most likely Mac too.

It did throw in a ton of junk contacts for me too though; lots of one-off addresses that I used once showed up. Took a while to delete all that, but now it works great.

Answer (score 0):

I have used [OggSync](http://oggsync.com/) to do this before Google offered support directly. I have been very pleased with Oggsync.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

I have been using the free service of [Nuevasync](http://nuevasync.com) for both Google Calendar and Contacts for almost a year now, and I can recommend it. Works like a charm, better than Google native stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sync will give you seamless and transparent contact syncing between the iPhone's native Contacts app and your contacts in Google - it will even sync photos you've linked with your contacts.

It will pull down all the contacts in the "My Contacts" section of Google Contacts, so it's best to make sure you've got that exactly how you want it before syncing.