# Is there a way to transfer all of your MobileMe contacts to Google Contacts?

Tags: google-contacts, mobileme

This is a followup question to the following question: [Is there a way to sync google contacts to your iPhone?](https://superuser.com/questions/2497/is-there-a-way-to-sync-google-contacts-to-your-iphone)

I am looking for an easy tool/method/way to transfer all of my contacts currently stored in MobileMe into Google Contacts.

What is the easiest way to do that? I have seen a tool that is designed to do that yet...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have a Mac, and you're syncing MobileMe contacts to your Address Book:

Open up Address Book, highlight all your contacts, then `click File > Export > Export vCard`.  Save the resulting vCard archive somewhere.  Open up http://google.com/contacts, click Import > Choose File, and select your archive.

If you have Windows, just export your contacts as a CSV or vCard archive from Outlook/Outlook Express/Windows Contacts and import them in the same manner.

You could also try [importing through Gmail](http://gmailblog.blogspot.com/2009/05/import-your-mail-and-contacts-from.html) using `Settings > Accounts and Imports > Import Mail and Contacts`, and then entering your MobileMe information.

Answer (score 1):

You can also sync your contacts directly from the Address Book once you synced it from MobileMe.

[This](http://www.google.com/support/contactsync/) article explains how this can be done.

Answer (score 0):

This worked well!  Actually, it was even easier than your full instructions indicated. I followed your instructions exactly about opening Address Book, selecting the contacts I wanted to export, then clicking *File > Export > Export V-Card*.  Next, I signed into my Gmail account, and all the contacts I had highlighted to export just showed up in my Gmail "Contacts" list without my having to do anything further.